# Read mdb file in Android ? using web service or xml

Tags: c#, php, android, asp.net, mobile

I want to make an android application which needs to access the database (MS Access *.mdb file) As their Current Application is in ASP and MDB ,

I want to read data from tables in this MDB file in Android

Pleas tell me technology to be used ?

what do i need to use ?

is it possible ?  like MDB to XML and then access XML file from Android ?

Comment: you don't. you migrate the data to the native sqlite engine and access it there. I highly doubt google would ever try to port over any microsoft database stuff.

Comment: convert mdb to sqlite and you have to create API which is reading data from database and response in json(MOst lightweight) then you can show in your app

Comment: What is doing the iOS tag in this thread?

Comment: in this example you can see Android Read Excel File from Website and display using a ListView.[http://nanostuffs.com/Blog/?p=969](http://nanostuffs.com/Blog/?p=969)

Comment: thanks but every time they would update the data using ASP and MDB file will be updated... so u prefer MDB to JSON ... API ?

Comment: is it possible ?  like MDB to XML and then access XML file from Android ?

Answer (score 1):

Your tags include ASP.NET and PHP. That's a good call - a sensible strategy would be to build a Web service around the database, and call it from the Android side. The exchange format between the service and the Android client is up to you - could be XML, could be JSON, or comma separated values for all I care.

What exactly are you stumped on - the Android part or the service part? The latter could be in pretty much any server side scripting tech - use the one you're more familiar with, and the one that's more friendly to your server environment (that means - ASP.NET if it's a Windows box, PHP if it's a *nix one). On the Android side, there's good old HttpClient class, and the respective format parsers (`String.split`, for the record, is a surprisingly efficient one :)).

Which tech - the one you are more familiar with (or have someone who's proficient in it). Can it be done - sure it can be. Will the SO community do it for you - probably not, this is not what we're here for.

I would not recommend, though, to *convert* the database to XML. Relational data are best kept in a relational database, and Access is not the worst one out there. Using XML as your wire format, however, is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your information surely I will try and update you